# Today observed a referral by site biztool.corp.google.com

Tags: google-analytics

Today observed a referral at my site from biztool.corp.google.com
Which was redirected to moma webpage

Can anybody help me out what was it whether a spam or what

Answer (score 2):

biztool.corp.google.com is the internal Google intranet.  Possibly someone from Google visited your site, but from your limited information, it is impossible to say.

MOMA is the title of that intranet - here is some information about it http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2007-11-28-n25.html